Langchain, call open AI
I am following quick start of Langchain to call open ai for LLM.
https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart
While running the below python code I am getting error.
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser

llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key="sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", "You are world class technical documentation writer."),
    ("user", "{input}")
])

chain = prompt | llm 
chain.invoke({"input": "how can langsmith help with testing?"})
output_parser = StrOutputParser()
chain = prompt | llm | output_parser
chain.invoke({"input": "how can langsmith help with testing?"})

I am getting below error:
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 902, in request
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 902, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 993, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}
PS C:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL>  c:; cd 'c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL'; & 'c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\yatanveer.singh\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '64396' '--' 'C:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\langchaindemo.py'
PS C:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL>  c:; cd 'c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL'; & 'c:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\yatanveer.singh\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '64413' '--' 'C:\Python\Sysint_NPL2SQL\langchaindemo.py'

Any pointer will help.
Thanks
Yatan

This got resolved after I bought credit from opeai. In short its not free to use.

Your code works in my env. The error you received
openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 

indicates your endpoint can't reach OpenAI's API

Thanks for response, are you using the paid key for open ai or are you using the trial.

Yes, to access services from OpenAI, you must pay. However, there are numerous methods to run a Large Language Model (LLM) locally on your computer or utilize HuggingFace, for instance, by using the HuggingFaceEndpoint function.
